# Transactions in HSQLDB ignores auto-commit

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, hsqldb

In the unit tests for my application, I wanted to test the persistence layer using HSQLDB. However, this requires me to explicitly commit on a transaction object. In one of the tests, this would not make the foo instance persistent:

```
final Foo foo = new Foo("someValue");

final EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestDataModel");
final EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

em.persist(foo);
```

Instead, I have to start and commit a transaction each time I want to persist and entity:

```
final Foo foo = new Foo("someValue");

final EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestDataModel");
final EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
final EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();

et.begin();
em.persist(foo);
et.commit();
```

I am not using any @Transactional annotations otherwise in my application. The classes I ultimately want to test are stateless services in a jax-rs application (The EntityManager is injected using [Needle](http://needle.spree.de/)), which does not require me to begin and commit transactions when storing entities. Some people around the net says that this issue is related to delayed writing in hsqldb, but I have added this to the connection url without yielding any difference. I have also enabled autocommit in the Hibernate configuration file and set the flush mode to always.

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="TestDataModel" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>Foo</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:db/db;shutdown=true;hsqldb.write_delay_millis=0;hsqldb.write_delay=false;" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="ALWAYS" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: You can enable the hsqldb.sqllog=3 to see all the sql and commits sent to database.